# Making bootstrap5 col only go down to footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

For this project I have to display a specific email adresses mailbox. In particular I need the 'Mail Card List' to be a scrollable component instead of stretching down the page, past the footer. I have tried using the 'max-height: ;' css style  but that sets a fixed height. I am after a variable height (so it will work on different screen sizes, etc).

[image: Example picture]

I
Any advice on how to achieve this (or even where to look) would be great. Thank you.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6fr9bh4v/4/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>TEMP MAIL</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">EMAIL</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Report</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- MAILBOX PAGE -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
                <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <span class="badge bg-secondary m-3">user@domain.com</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success mt-4 mb-4 mx-1">Return</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-4 mb-4 mx-1">Refresh</button>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <!-- BASE - Search component -->
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Search</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- EMAIL VIEW ONLY | ADD -->
            <div class="col-7">


                <div>
                    <dl class="row">
                        <dt class="col-2 text-end m-0">
                            From:
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-10 m-0">
                            Larry
                        </dd>
                        <dt class="col-2 text-end m-0">
                            To:
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-10 m-0">
                            Dan
                        </dd>
                        <dt class="col-2 text-end m-0">
                            Date:
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-10 m-0">
                            1/1/2000
                        </dd>
                        <dt class="col-2 text-end m-0">
                            Subject:
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-10 m-0">
                            Test email!
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mt-2 mb-2">Delete</button>
                    <br>
                    <!--
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mt-2 mb-2">Delete</button>
                    -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <!-- EMAIL CARD LIST -->
            <div class="col-3" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                <!-- EMAIL CARD -->
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 1</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 2</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 3</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- EMAIL VIEW ONLY -->
            <div class="col-9">SHOW EMAIL HERE</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container-fluid text-center p-4" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
            THIS IS A FOOTER
            <br>
            <a class="text-reset fw-bold" href="#">FOOTER LINK</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

<!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Replace the inline style rule for overflow, you are using bootstrap, use the [`overflow-scroll` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/overflow/).
- For the overflow to work you need to give it height, but since this is to be dynamic (to work across devices), so you will need to make it [relative to viewport](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport)

  ```
  <!-- EMAIL LIST -->
  <div class="col-3 overflow-scroll vh-100">
  .
  .
  .
  </div>
  ```

With the above changes you'll see improvements but, you will need to consider the height that the rest of the elements (navigation etc) take. And when you have this in pixels, you can use [CSS `calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) to subtract it from the full viewport height. Create a class for your custom height relative to the viewport, for example:

```
.custom-height {
  height: calc(100vh - 400px);
  min-height: 60px; /* add min-height to prevent it from becoming way too small if not enough vertical space*/
}
```

- To allow space for the footer add margin on the "mailbox page" container div, `mb-5`
- Remove `fixed-bottom` from `<footer>`

*Full code*:

```css
.custom-height {
  height: calc(100vh - 400px);
  min-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>TEMP MAIL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/ -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LarryMail</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Report</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- API ACCESS | ON BACK LIST
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">API</a>
                    </li>
                    -->
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <select class="form-select me-2" aria-label="Default select example">
                        <option selected>Select Domain</option>
                        <option value="1">@crazyforher.com</option>
                        <option value="2">@etc...</option>
                        <option value="3">@etc...</option>
                    </select>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success me-2" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!--
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    -->

    <!-- HOME PAGE
    <main class="flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="mt-5">LarryMail</h1>
            <p class="lead">Unlimited mailboxes. Courtesy of Larry.</p>
            <form class="d-flex">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <select class="form-select me-2" aria-label="Default select example">
                    <option selected>Select Domain</option>
                    <option value="1">@crazyforher.com</option>
                    <option value="2">@etc...</option>
                    <option value="3">@etc...</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success me-2" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
    -->

    <!-- MAILBOX PAGE -->
    <div class="container mb-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
                <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <span class="badge bg-secondary m-3">admin@crazyforher.com</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success mt-4 mb-4 mx-1">Return</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-4 mb-4 mx-1">Refresh</button>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <!-- BASE - Search component -->
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Search</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- EMAIL VIEW ONLY | ADD -->
            <div class="col-7">

                <!-- IF MAILBOX EMPTY
                <p>
                    Select a message at left, or enter a different username into the box on upper right.
                </p>
                -->
                <div>
                    <dl class="row">
                        <dt class="col-2 text-end m-0">
                            From:
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-10 m-0">
                            Larry
                        </dd>
                        <dt class="col-2 text-end m-0">
                            To:
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-10 m-0">
                            Larry
                        </dd>
                        <dt class="col-2 text-end m-0">
                            Date:
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-10 m-0">
                            Larry
                        </dd>
                        <dt class="col-2 text-end m-0">
                            Subject:
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="col-10 m-0">
                            Larry
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mt-2 mb-2">Delete</button>
                    <br>
                    <!--
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mt-2 mb-2">Delete</button>
                    -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <!-- EMAIL LIST -->
            <div class="col-3 overflow-scroll custom-height">
                <!-- EMAIL CARD -->
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 1</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 2</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 3</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row card mt-1 mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-block px-4">
                        <div class="row">Email Subject 4</div>
                        <div class="row">Test@Domain.com</div>
                        <div class="row">TIME</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- EMAIL VIEW ONLY -->
            <div class="col-9">SHOW EMAIL HERE</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid text-center p-4" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
            THIS IS A FOOTER
            <br>
            <a class="text-reset fw-bold" href="#">FOOTER LINK</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

<!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```